# WRAP_CONTENT not working for dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout were i display users chat with orentation vertical. Each message is placed inside a textview an the textview is then added to a relative layout an then added to the linear layout.
both the relative layout and the textview are created dynamically for each message in the chat. but my problem is that the textview is not showing the message fully.

[image: this is the screen shot of the chat]

In the image above the full message is not showing, and in the right side of the chat the width of the first view affect the others and not wrapping the message as suppose.

so how can i get it work, i want the textview to wrap according to  it's content.

This is my code

```
  rLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    msgLayout1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    msgLayout2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //msgLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);

    msgLayout1.leftMargin = 20;
    msgLayout2.rightMargin = 20;
    rLayout.topMargin = 30;

   msgLayout2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    msgLayout2.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    msgView = findViewById(R.id.msgView);

    msgLayout1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_INHERIT);
```

And this is the function that appends the message

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void addChat(String msg, String key) {
    int status = 0;
    if (key.equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
        status = 2;
    } else {
        status = 1;
    }

    RelativeLayout nr = new RelativeLayout(this);



    TextView nt = new TextView(this);
    nt.setPadding(20,10,20,10);
    if (status == 1) {

        nt.setText(msg);
        nt.setBackground(getMyImage("fborder"));
        nt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8d39c4"));
        nt.setLayoutParams(msgLayout1);
    } else {

        nt.setText(msg);
        nt.setBackground(getMyImage("uborder"));
        nt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d1d2d5"));
        nt.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
        nt.setLayoutParams(msgLayout2);

    }
    nr.setLayoutParams(rLayout);
    nr.addView(nt);

    msgView.addView(nr);

}
```

rLayout is the layoutParam for the relativeLayout that will contain the textview,
msgLayout1 is the layoutParam for left message-textview,
msgLayout2 is the layoutParam for right side message-textview

Comment: You are setting `WRAP_CONTENT` to your rLayout. Try using `MATCH_PARENT` there.

Comment: I tried MATCH_PARENT for both hight and width but no message displayed at all

Comment: When i use MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP_CONTENT for height i still get same problem

Comment: Can you try to set width like this `textview.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` or `textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
`

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: Texttview.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  i used the code as u suggested but the chat stop displaying any message at all, but once i remove that line it goes back to the original problem

Comment: Is the feature implemented using LIstview or RecylerView? And Is the `addChat` method inside the some adapter?

Comment: @CFrancis Did you get a solution?

Comment: Yes i already solve the problem, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is because i declared the layout params at global scope,so i  was able to solve the problem by adding all the layout params into the addChat() function, there by making there declaration local to the function. So when ever a chat is appended a new layout param is created for that chat.